# javascript get DISTINCT count like sql from the data

Tags: javascript

```
        data = [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "id": 47,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.8,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.6,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "setosa"
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "id": 48,
            "sepallengthcm": 4.6,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.2,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "setosa"
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "id": 49,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.3,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.7,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.5,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "jennifer"
        },
        {
            "index": 3,
            "id": 50,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.0,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "setosa"
        },
        {
            "index": 4,
            "id": 97,
            "sepallengthcm": 12.0,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
            "unnamed:_3": 4.2,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
            "species": "jennifer"
        },
        {
            "index": 5,
            "id": 98,
            "sepallengthcm": 6.2,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
            "unnamed:_3": 4.3,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
            "species": "jennifer"
        },
        {
            "index": 6,
            "id": 99,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.5,
            "unnamed:_3": 3.0,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.1,
            "species": "kajol"
        },
        {
            "index": 7,
            "id": 100,
            "sepallengthcm": 11.0,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.8,
            "unnamed:_3": 7.0,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
            "species": "floaw"
        },
        {
            "index": 8,
            "id": 101,
            "sepallengthcm": 6.3,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
            "unnamed:_3": 6.0,
            "petalwidthcm": 2.5,
            "species": "Iris-flower"
        },
        {
            "index": 9,
            "id": 102,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.8,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.7,
            "unnamed:_3": 5.1,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.9,
            "species": "Iris-flower"
        }
        ]
```

Here is my input data.
I am trying to achive distict count of this data using spcific field

result = distictCount("species")

```
    result = [
            {
            "species": "Iris-flower",
            "sepallengthcm": 2
            },
            {
            "species": "floaw",
            "sepallengthcm": 1
            },
            {
            "species": "jennifer",
            "sepallengthcm": 3
            },
            {
            "species": "kajol",
            "sepallengthcm": 1
            },
            {
            "species": "setosa",
            "sepallengthcm": 3
            }
        ]


SELECT species, COUNT(DISTINCT sepallengthcm) as sepallengthcm FROM soubhagyairis GROUP BY species;
```

My sql query does the work. But, i wants to achive this using javascript.
Please take a look.

How can we do that

Thanks

My sql query does the work. But, i wants to achive this using javascript.
Please take a look.

How can we do that

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const distinctCount = (data, group, key) => {
    return Array.from(new Set(data.map(d => d[group])))
      .map(g => {return {
        [group]: g,
        [key]: data.filter(d => d[group] == g).length
  }});
}
```

Using `new Set(data.map(d => d[group]))` makes a Set which does the hard work of SQL DISTINCT for you and using `Array.from(etc)` converts to a regular Javascript Array.

The `.map(...)` then creates a new object for each DISTINCT species and finds the count using `data.filter(d => d[group] == g).length`

```js
data = [
  {
    "index": 0,
    "id": 47,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.8,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.6,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "id": 48,
    "sepallengthcm": 4.6,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.2,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "id": 49,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.3,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.7,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.5,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "jennifer"
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "id": 50,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.0,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
    "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
    "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
    "species": "setosa"
  },
  {
    "index": 4,
    "id": 97,
    "sepallengthcm": 12.0,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
    "unnamed:_3": 4.2,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
    "species": "jennifer"
  },
  {
    "index": 5,
    "id": 98,
    "sepallengthcm": 6.2,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
    "unnamed:_3": 4.3,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
    "species": "jennifer"
  },
  {
    "index": 6,
    "id": 99,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.5,
    "unnamed:_3": 3.0,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.1,
    "species": "kajol"
  },
  {
    "index": 7,
    "id": 100,
    "sepallengthcm": 11.0,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.8,
    "unnamed:_3": 7.0,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
    "species": "floaw"
  },
  {
    "index": 8,
    "id": 101,
    "sepallengthcm": 6.3,
    "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
    "unnamed:_3": 6.0,
    "petalwidthcm": 2.5,
    "species": "Iris-flower"
  },
  {
    "index": 9,
    "id": 102,
    "sepallengthcm": 5.8,
    "sepalwidthcm": 2.7,
    "unnamed:_3": 5.1,
    "petalwidthcm": 1.9,
    "species": "Iris-flower"
  }
];

const distinctCount = (data, group, key) => {
    return Array.from(new Set(data.map(d => d[group])))
        .map(g => {return {
        [group]: g,
        [key]: data.filter(d => d[group] == g).length
  }});
}

console.log(distinctCount(data, "species", "sepallengthcm"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using for loop:

Snippet:

```js
var data = [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "id": 47,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.8,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.6,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "setosa"
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "id": 48,
            "sepallengthcm": 4.6,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.2,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "setosa"
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "id": 49,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.3,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.7,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.5,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "jennifer"
        },
        {
            "index": 3,
            "id": 50,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.0,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "setosa"
        },
        {
            "index": 4,
            "id": 97,
            "sepallengthcm": 12.0,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
            "unnamed:_3": 4.2,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
            "species": "jennifer"
        },
        {
            "index": 5,
            "id": 98,
            "sepallengthcm": 6.2,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
            "unnamed:_3": 4.3,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
            "species": "jennifer"
        },
        {
            "index": 6,
            "id": 99,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.5,
            "unnamed:_3": 3.0,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.1,
            "species": "kajol"
        },
        {
            "index": 7,
            "id": 100,
            "sepallengthcm": 11.0,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.8,
            "unnamed:_3": 7.0,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
            "species": "floaw"
        },
        {
            "index": 8,
            "id": 101,
            "sepallengthcm": 6.3,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
            "unnamed:_3": 6.0,
            "petalwidthcm": 2.5,
            "species": "Iris-flower"
        },
        {
            "index": 9,
            "id": 102,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.8,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.7,
            "unnamed:_3": 5.1,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.9,
            "species": "Iris-flower"
        }
        ];
        
var result = [];
var intermediate = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    intermediate[i] = data[i].species;
}
intermediate.sort();
var n = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= intermediate.length; i++) {
    
    if (intermediate[i] !== intermediate[i - 1]) {
        if (intermediate[i - 1] !== undefined) {
            result.push({"flower": intermediate[i-1], "n": n});
        }
        n = 1;
    } else {
        n++;
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Code:

```
var result = [];
var intermediate = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    intermediate[i] = data[i].species;
}
intermediate.sort();
var n = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= intermediate.length; i++) {
    
    if (intermediate[i] !== intermediate[i - 1]) {
        if (intermediate[i - 1] !== undefined) {
            result.push({"flower": intermediate[i-1], "n": n});
        }
        n = 1;
    } else {
        n++;
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It is giving me as a list

Answer (score 1):

I used underscore.js countBy method for that.

```js
data = [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "id": 47,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.8,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.6,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "setosa"
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "id": 48,
            "sepallengthcm": 4.6,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.2,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "setosa"
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "id": 49,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.3,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.7,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.5,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "jennifer"
        },
        {
            "index": 3,
            "id": 50,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.0,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
            "unnamed:_3": 1.4,
            "petalwidthcm": 0.2,
            "species": "setosa"
        },
        {
            "index": 4,
            "id": 97,
            "sepallengthcm": 12.0,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
            "unnamed:_3": 4.2,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
            "species": "jennifer"
        },
        {
            "index": 5,
            "id": 98,
            "sepallengthcm": 6.2,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.9,
            "unnamed:_3": 4.3,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
            "species": "jennifer"
        },
        {
            "index": 6,
            "id": 99,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.1,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.5,
            "unnamed:_3": 3.0,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.1,
            "species": "kajol"
        },
        {
            "index": 7,
            "id": 100,
            "sepallengthcm": 11.0,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.8,
            "unnamed:_3": 7.0,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.3,
            "species": "floaw"
        },
        {
            "index": 8,
            "id": 101,
            "sepallengthcm": 6.3,
            "sepalwidthcm": 3.3,
            "unnamed:_3": 6.0,
            "petalwidthcm": 2.5,
            "species": "Iris-flower"
        },
        {
            "index": 9,
            "id": 102,
            "sepallengthcm": 5.8,
            "sepalwidthcm": 2.7,
            "unnamed:_3": 5.1,
            "petalwidthcm": 1.9,
            "species": "Iris-flower"
        }
        ];

let a = _.countBy(data, function(item) {
  return item.species;
});

tmp = [];
for (const key in a) {
  val = {}
  val.species = key;
  val.sepallengthcm = a[key]
  
  tmp.push(val);
}

console.log(tmp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.12.0/underscore-min.js" integrity="sha512-BDXGXSvYeLxaldQeYJZVWXJmkisgMlECofWFXKpWwXnfcp/R708nrs/BtNLH5cb/5TE7aeYRTDBRXu6kRL4VeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Example
https://jsfiddle.net/8Lph7503/

Source:
https://underscorejs.org/#countBy